# Add html class to body

Tags: views, theming, entities

I've got a block created with views, which displaying a slider.
The slider is created as an unpublished content type with two field collections:

**Settings**[one value]:

- selectors type: thumbs or bullets
- slider class: fixed position, faded etc.

**Slider content**[multiple values]:

- slide class
- content class
- Image
- content

I do not use views slideshow module
I'm using views-view--slider-block.tpl.php file to customize the output

All works, but I have stuck with one specific setting "fixed position" - this setting should add to html a special class, which I guess can be added only by preprocess_html function:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) { 
    if ( SLIDER HAS "fixed" SETTING ){
        $variables['classes_array'][] = 'slider_fixed';
    }
}
```

the problem is:

1. how to compose the if statement?
2. Did I have to load $view object which allows me to check what
   setting is used?

I'm looking for the solution which has the lowest influence on the performance.

any suggestions?

Comment: If you can add this class to the html of the block in use instead of the page body, you should be able to access the Views object as `$view` in your Views template.

Comment: Yes, I have a variable with the setting in views template file. The problem is how to pass it to MYTHEME_preprocess_html()

Comment: right, but can the slider js you have use a class in its wrapping block's div instead of looking at the page's body/html tag?

Comment: this class has to be in body to achieve the effect (fixed position of the slider towards to body)

Comment: gotcha.  grr.  there really isn't any direct way to do what you want to do then.

Comment: Please add your solution as an Answer.

Comment: @Jack good job my +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Context API allow to pass a variable from view.tpl to template.php file

**Example:**

In view.tpl file :

context_set('slider_settings', 'slider_class', 'fixed_position');

In theme template file :

function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

```
$slider_class = context_get('slider_settings', 'slider_class');
if ($slider_class == 'fixed_position'){
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'slider_fixed';
}
```

}

It is an aswer for my own question, because I found a solution by myself, and it might be useful for someone I think..

Comment: This is excellent, using it on a current project, thanks.